# PyWinAuto with out using "child_window"

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have NO return on child_window when the program is in its state i expect to work in.
I need a way to edit the text field but literally all examples and google searches i have done show no examples of implementation EXCEPT when using child_window

this should put Test into the edit field

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="DaVinci Resolve Studio - Template")
    #app.DaVinciResolveStudioTemplate.print_control_identifiers()
    Title = app.DaVinciResolveStudioTemplate.['TitleEdit', 'Edit8'].wrapper_object()
    Title.type_keys("Test")
```

it returns a syntax error

I have read teh documentation and i HONESTLY have no idea how to initiate the return with out a child window. Googing "no child_window" with multiple iterations has yielded me hours wasted and NOT ONE solution.

[if text is entered the child_window appears in returns, but that isnt how the program start's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPCq1.png)

[This is the native return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi2nT.png)

please, explain it for me how im supposed to seach/grab/interact with out child window? with a example please because this has me at a loss

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error is in line `Title = app.DaVinciResolveStudioTemplate.['TitleEdit', 'Edit8'].wrapper_object()`.

This line should be written as either `Title = app.DaVinciResolveStudioTemplate['TitleEdit', 'Edit8'].wrapper_object()` or `Title = app.DaVinciResolveStudioTemplate.Edit8.wrapper_object()`.